# What is the benefit of defining the "or" operation in clojure as a macro rather than simply as a function?

Tags: clojure

I'm hoping the explanation will give me better insight into the advantages of using macros.

Comment: Aside: The first rule of Macro Club is *don't write macros*. Which is to say: There are situations where macros are absolutely essential (`core.async` couldn't possibly be a library as opposed to a core language feature without them), but if you aren't in one of those situations, they're best avoided.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a function, all arguments are evaluated before its invocation.

This means that `or` as a function cannot be lazy, whereas a macro can rewrite `or` into an `if` statement that only evaluates branches when it's necessary to do so.

---

A bit more concretely, consider:

```
(or (cached-lookup) (expensive-operation))
```

...what it gets rewritten into looks like:

```
(let [or__1234__auto (cached-lookup)]
  (if or__1234__auto
    or__1234__auto
    (expensive-operation)))
```

...such that we only evaluate `(expensive-operation)` if the return value of `(cached-lookup)` is `nil` or `false`. You couldn't do that with a function while implementing regular JVM calling conventions: `expensive-operation` would *always* be evaluated, whether or not its result is needed, so that its result could be passed as an argument to the function.

---

Incidentally, you *can* implement a function in this case if you take zero-argument functions as your arguments. That is to say, you can do this:

```
(defn or*
  ([] false)                                                ; 0-arg case
  ([func-one] (func-one))                                   ; 1-arg case
  ([func-one func-two]                                      ; optimized two-arg case
   (let [first-result (func-one)]
     (if first-result
       first-result
       (func-two))))
  ([func-one func-two & rest]                               ; general case
   (let [first-result (func-one)]
     (if first-result
       first-result
       (apply or* func-two rest)))))
```

*When you must implement a macro, it's often helpful to have it generate "thunks" (anonymous functions), and pass them to higher-order functions such as this one*; this substantially aids composability, as a function can be wrapped, modified, or called using higher-level functions such as `partial` in ways a macro cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Guess what would happen if `or` and `and` were functions in this case?

```
(defn some [f l]
  (and (seq l)
       (or (f (first l)) 
           (some f (rest l)))))
```

If you guessed it would never terminate you are right! In fact both of them are macros expanding to `if`. Macros allows us to make code that gets translated to something else before it's run so a macro doesn't have access to values, just the code.

Comment: It terminates regardless unless `l` is endless.

Comment: @Thumbnail No, in fact it doesn't, because it unconditionally makes a recursive call to `some`. It *looks* like it terminates because you're used to `and` and `or` short-circuiting, but the point of this answer is to demonstrate a case where it's important that they short-circuit: if they didn't, this function would never terminate!

Comment: @amalloy Ah! True.